# rails react browserify TypeError: Object function has no method 'extend'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, flux, browserify-rails

I'm trying to make a web app using rails, react, and browserify. I've been following [this tutorial](http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/01/29/react-plus-flux-backed-by-rails-api-part-2/), and since I want server-side rendering, I've used [this repo](https://github.com/olance/rails-react-browserify-example) as a starting point, and followed the tutorial mentioned in the README file.

Although I think I've done things as the mentioned articles suggest, I cant figure out how to solve the following error:

`TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            } has no method 'extend'`

If you want to reproduce the error, clone [my repo](https://github.com/throoze/vendata), which is opensource and its on github, and go to the feature branch `auth`, instal the gems and npm packages and lift the server:

`$ cd path_to_project
$ git checkout -b feature/auth
$ bundle
$ npm install
$ bundle exec rails server`

I would really appreciate any help, since i'm currently stuck here. Also, I'm new to react, so I don't know pretty much where to look for the problem.

**EDIT**: By request in the comments, I've removed the stacktrace in order to make the question more readable. If you need any extra information, please let me know.

Comment: Can you edit your post, please? It is not easy to legible.

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński : done, could you figure something out?

Comment: @Throoze Unrelated but if you have a moment, would you mind trying browserify-rails 2.0.2 and see if it works well for you? There were some performance improvements but I'd like to confirm it is working correctly for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to be using the [`j-toker`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker) CommonJS package which internally uses `jQuery`'s `ajax` API. jQuery is incompatible with server side rendering since it needs a `document` element to load itself, and it only exists in the browser, not in the server. The solution is not yet at hand, but as [J-Toker's author has indicated](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker/issues/18#issuecomment-155910737), he's about to release a new library that covers the case of server side rendering.

So, to anyone encountering a similar error, check if you are using `jquery` or any other package that in turns depends on `jquery`, or requires having a `document` DOM element, and try using a server-side-rendering-safe alternative.